# Ideas for band site, which technology to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, silverlight

I am attempting to design and build a website for my friends band. There is minimal content to be included such as bio,news,enbemdded Audio/Visual material. My web dev expertise is average.

I'm basicaly looking for inspiration, I was edging towards embedding a silverlight deepzoom xap object to add some visual stimulation, perhaps by featuring a high res photo of the bandshardware/equipment which zooms when mouseover occurs. Does anyone have any cool ideas for a central feature for this site, and which way to approact it in terms of technique (js,css,silverlight etc)

If anyone has any immediate ideas which they think would be cool then I am eager to hear them!

Also if anyone can link me to any cool band sites they have come across recently I would be greatful,nothing too complicated though please I will be doing all the work myself. Im want the site to be simple but have a certain wow factor!

Comment: Possibly a [Doctype](http://doctype.com/) question, I'm not convinced that this is, in any way, ['programming related.'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Actually, sounds to me this question is more appropriate for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just use wordpress. It is customisable with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2):

I would exclude silverlight because it slows down the website and the user need the plugin to be installed. 
For a simple stack of technologies, what you have tagged is allright!

You should (as mentioned by @Navi) download some wordpress/joomla band templates and try to understand how they're build, and then try to build your own webpages

Also for example you could try to understand some cool TABLELESS website structure (http://www.tommyemmanuel.com/..I like both the musician and the website :D ), and first of all you should try to obtain the same structure. Second of all you should apply some nice css and some jQuery/mootools/etc dom effects.

Comment: i have already been on the prowl for good band templates in CMS, but i didnt find much to be honest :/

Answer (score 1):

Look into Drupal. It has built in support for blogs, forums and a lot of other cool features.It is easily extendable for anything you need. For example, [Michael Jackson's](http://www.michaeljackson.com/us/home) official website is built with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CMS or similar is great if the band want an easy way to put in their own content after you are done with the site. A search for 'lightweight cms' might get you a step further. :)

You can look up similar bands at myspace and check out their webpages for nice features.